# I find this answer is irrelevant to my questions

Tags: support, flags

I have asked this [question]  ([Is there a word which describes something being both beautiful and ugly at the same time?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458136/is-there-a-word-which-describes-something-being-both-beautiful-and-ugly-at-the-s)) on Stack Exchange English and I suspect the user [Kris](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/14666/kris) is receiving upvote because he has uploaded some troll pictures and he has high points. I already commented him saying that his answer is not related to my question. He is not replying to why he answered it. Also, the answer which I accepted and which is actually relevant is under looked. I don't want that other users should get wrong answer when they look my question. 
I have also tried Flagging the answer, but one was declined and other is pending.

I have high regards for stack exchange and I need answer for this question.

Answer (score 12):

The answer you have selected has the green checkmark, and that answer will always be displayed first. This is you telling the community that your question has been answered, and as far as you are concerned, it is the best answer.

But people can disagree, and upvote another answer. The fact that you don't like one answer does not give you the right to ask the moderators to intervene in some way (how?) or (worse) delete the post. As long as the post submitted *is* on-topic and has, preferably, supporting references; it is an answer. Consequently, it should stay.

Comment: The Q sounded like yet another  misguided attempt to abridge rights to free speech...quite common these days.